# Firestore Security Rules - How to restrict users to reading only specific documents?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to display public information about users in a view, but I don't want the user to be able to **get()** a list of all users in my **/users/{userID}/public** collection. I know I can restrict access so that only the **public** collection is viewable. But that also would let someone scrub the entire database to see all the public users.

What sort of rules could I use to limit access so that a specific document is specified? For example:

```
db.collection('users').get()
```

Would be denied. But:

```
db.collection('users').doc('abc123').collection('public').get()
```

...would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing about the relationship between /users/x and /users/x/public that makes it hard to protect them separately.  They are completely different collections and can be protected separately without conflict.  The only time you would have a problem is if you chose to use a glob wildcard, which is not normally used.

If you don't specify any rule for /users, then no access will be allowed.  The rule for your first request is to simply write no rule.  (Unless you want users to read their individual document, then just write that rule, and it will still also prevent anyone from getting a list of users.)

The rule for your second request can be enabled for everyone simply by writing:

```
match /users/{uid}/public/{id} {
  allow read;
}
```

That rule will have no effect on the documents immediately in /users, because they don't match the pattern.  And any other rule that matches /users/{uid} wouldn't affect any subcollections for the same reason - no match.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I sort of answered my own question. You can just grant read access to your users **public** sub-collection but block access to the specific **user** doc.

For those Googling here later, something like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userID} {
            allow read, write, delete: if isAdmin();

            match /public/{publicID} {
                allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```